# Why does nginx initially redirect to incorrect upstream but after ctrl-shift-r it redirects properly?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

This is my nginx config (I'm no expert here):

```
upstream Vault {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

upstream Frontend {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  http2 on;
  server_name example;

  ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/certs/example-selfsigned.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/private/example-selfsigned.key;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

  # Allow large attachments
  client_max_body_size 128M;

  location ^~ /vault/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://Vault/vault/;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://Frontend/;
  }
}
```

This is a webapp that's only ever used internally. Nginx, Frontend, and Vault are all docker containers. Frontend is a react app and Vault is a Vaultwarden instance. Frontend is accesible at the root of https://example/. The Vault container should be accessible at https://example/vault/.

The problem is that whether I browse directly to https://example/vault/ or click the menu button on the Frontend, it initially resolves to a blank page with my react apps template but when I refresh (ctrl-shift-r) the page it goes to the Vaultwarden login page. I want it to resolve to Vaultwarden without the refresh.

Is there something wrong with my nginx configuration? While I don't think it has anything to do with my react app, I'm down to share whatever information needed to help get this working.

Let me know if you need anything else from me and if you have any questions. THANKS!

I've commented out the `location /` section and the Vaultwarden page comes up immediately.

I've changed the order but it didn't change anything.

I've put the config into https://nginx.viraptor.info/ and it said it should resolve to Vault over Frontend.